# Problem with small values using linear dimension in graph package of Metapost

Tags: graphs, metapost

Making a graph I used the following mp-file to make a graph.

```
input graph;

beginfig(0)
    draw begingraph(5in, 3in);
        setcoords(log, linear);
        glabel.lft(btex Time etex, OUT);
        glabel.bot(btex Size etex, OUT);
        gdraw "test.d" withcolor red;
    endgraph;
endfig;

bye;
```

If `test.d` file is

```
1 1e-06
2 3e-06
4 5e-06
```

then I get a strange graph:
[image]

Nothing but labels changes if I  write `setcoords(linear, linear)`. However it goes right if I change it to `setcoords(log, log)` :
[image]

This is not a solution since I need to have `linear` second dimension. Making this MWE I found out that everything is OK if I use integers (or not-too-small real numbers) in the `test.d` file.

```
1 1
2 3
4 5
```

[image]

And I've got the most unexpected graph on the edge between "good" and "bad" numbers.

```
1 1e-05
2 3e-05
4 5e-05
```

[image]

So finally I have the following solution to make nice-looking graphs: modify the data file multiplying all *y*-coordinates to make them not too small. However it's hard to think this solution as being not-too-bad. The question is how to make a nice-looking `(log, linear)` graph without any modification of the data file even if it contains all values below some critical value?

Comment: From the MetaPost [manual](https://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpman.pdf) (page 14): "Numeric quantities in MetaPost are represented in fixed point arithmetic as integer multiples of 1/65536, the smallest positive value". This number is 1.5e-05 so your numbers are too small.

Comment: @Marijn so there is no way to display correctly values like 1e-8?

Comment: It looks like such values are all rounded to 0. Interestingly though with the log/log scale it does work as you noticed, so MetaPost is using a different calculation method there - however I don't know if and how this could be applied to linear scales as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the "simplest" way to fix this, is to use the facility to scale the numbers to a nice range.  In your original case, you might convert them to milliseconds, like so.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
input graph
beginfig(1);
    draw begingraph(5in, 3in);
        setcoords(log, linear);
        glabel.lft(btex Time (ms) etex, OUT);
        glabel.bot(btex Size etex, OUT);
        % gdraw "test.d" withcolor red;
        interim Gpaths:=log;
        gdraw Mreadpath("test.d") shifted (0,6*Mten) withcolor red;
    endgraph;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

This is wrapped up in `luamplib`, so compile with `lualatex` (or adapt for plain MP), to get this:

[image]

This approach is explained at the end of section 3 in [the manual](https://tug.org/docs/metapost/mpgraph.pdf).  In summary, `Mreadpath` reads from the `test.d` file into a `<path>` variable with the coordinates in the internal `mlog` form.   You can adjust this path by scaling or shifting.  In this case, it's shifted by `(0, 6 * Mten)` where `Mten` is the internal mlog form of 10, so this adds 6 times log ten to each y-coordinate, or in other words, multiplies by 10**6 = 1,000,000.   Notice that I also changed the label to say `(ms)`.